# Alternative for strings.xml (It is in android) for IOS

Tags: swift

There is `strings.xml` in Android which we can write Strings in.
I want to do the same thing using swift. So I wrote string in a String file

```
//sample.String
"name" = "Sara";
"family" = "Young";
```

But I don't know how to access these strings in viewControllers.

Comment: Is this for localisation?

Comment: @Sweeper no its not. I want to use "name" in some of  viewCotrollers and I want it to be replaced with "Sara"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lot's of was to do this.

- Create a `Constants` type that has static `let`s:

  ```
  class Constants {
      static let name = "Sara"
      static let family = "Young"
  }
  ```

  you can use these like:

  ```
  someLabel.text = Constants.name
  ```
- Declare constants globally

  Create a swift file named `Constants.swift` and declare constants:

  ```
  let name = "Sara"
  let family = "Young"
  ```

  If you use this method, I suggest that you add a prefix to each constant to avoid name conflicts.
- Use a dictionary:

  ```
  let constantsDict = [
      "name": "Sara",
      "family": "Young"
  ]
  ```

  Usage:

  ```
  someLabel.text = constantsDict["name"]!
  ```

  Obviously, the compile won't check whether the key is valid or not if you use this method.

Comment: Thanks. so we cannot create an xml file similar to Android and put strings there?

Comment: @FattanehTalebi Well, we can create something called a "Strings file" to put strings in, but that is mainly used for localization purposes. See here for more info on localisation: https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881